# Javascript window resize possible race condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, race-condition

Given the following test case, the expected behaviour is that the lightblue element exactly matches the size of the red parent as the browser window is resized.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"/></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #viewport{
        width: 100%;
        height: 30%;
        background-color: red;
    }
    #child{
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="viewport"><div id='child'></div></div>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', function(){
            var width = $('#viewport').innerWidth();
            var height = $('#viewport').innerHeight();
            $('#child').css('height', height+'px');
            $('#child').css('width', width+'px');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The actual behaviour on chrome 36.0.1985.143 is that sometimes (especially at smaller window sizes) the child element is set exactly 5px less tall and/or 1px less wide than the parent element. The issue stops happening  if `$('#child').css('width', width+'px');` is commented out.

It has been reported that the issue doesn't occur on firefox.

A similar issue seems to have been picked up on http://thewebivore.com/using-settimeout-win-race-condition-changing-views/ however I haven't been able to mitigate it with a timeout < 10 ms which is not really a solution.

Comment: Not seeing the issue at all http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/kpmL8tuh/ Chrome 37.0.2062.94

Comment: What blue element? the above test case outputs an empty window as it is. By the way, why can't you set the size in css itself..?

Comment: @Moogs the example doesn't work with JSFiddle. It should be run straight in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've plugged your example code into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxe4njs/1/) and I seem to be having a host of other problems.

However, if I use `vh` and `vw` instead of `%`, I get much better results:

```
#viewport {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 30vh;
    background-color: red;
}
#child {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxe4njs/2/)...

Comment: Can confirm it works, but not really an attractive solution due to compatibility. Also note that the JSFiddle wrapper causes entirely different behaviour for my example. It should be run straight in a browser.